# Button to open a form with Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a button to open a form with Javascript but it's not working and I can't figure out why. I'm just putting here the code for the button and the form, not the whole page behind it. Hope someone can help me.
Also would like to know how and where to submit the information once the form is completed.

html :

```
<div class="open-btn">
  <button id="show-modal"><strong>Open Form</strong></button>
</div>
<div class="modal modal--hidden">
  <div class="modal_contents">
    <div class="modal_close-bar"><span>X</span></div>
    <form id="open-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Subject">
      <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.modal {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.modal_contents {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 2rem 4rem;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.modal_close-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: -2rem;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgba(234, 203, 193, 0.4);
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(143, 126, 121, 0.4);
}
.modal--hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const toggleModal = () => {
 document.querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle('.modal--hidden');
};

document.querySelector('#show-modal').addEventListener('click', toggleModal);

document.querySelector('#open-form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  toggleModal(); 
});
```

Comment: Have you checked that what is inside toggleModal function is been executed?

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the point before `modal--hidden` and it works.

`document.querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle('modal--hidden');`

Comment: I tested it myself and it worked. Could it be influenced by anything else? Is there more JavaScript code?

Comment: No, just that. Can it be something on the rest of the HTML?

Comment: Is there an error message in the console? If not, it can only be due to HTML or CSS or maybe the browser still has an old version of the JavaScript code, to be sure clear the cache and hard reload the page.

Comment: There's no error message on the console. I've clear the cache and it doesn't work either. I opened it on safari and the same happened. Is just weird because when I pass the code to codepen it works. I've tried to change the javascript logic to a similar one and nothing happens again. Not sure what to do anymore.

Comment: Maybe the JavaScript file gets not loaded at all? Just insert a `debugger;` and see if the method getting called.

Comment: Nothing happens :(

Comment: How did you integrate the JavaScript file? Try to write an `alert()` at the beginning of the file, if there is no message then the file will not be imported properly.

Comment: You're right, it was just not connected properly to the JavaScript file!

Answer (score 0):

The only typo mistake you did was this:

```
document.querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle('.modal--hidden');
```

Just remove the dot before 'modal--hidden', like this:

```
document.querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle('modal--hidden');
```

Also, to get the form data, first give names to all your form elements:

```
    <form id="open-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
        <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Then, capture form data using FormData object:

```
document.querySelector('#open-form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  toggleModal();
  var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('#open-form'));
  console.log("Name:" + formData.get('name'),
    "Email:" + formData.get('email'),
    "Subject:" + formData.get('subject'),
    "Message:" + formData.get('message'));
});
```

[For complete code, click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvshfc)

Comment: Hey, thanks for that! I was trying now to get the form data with this last bit of code but it gives me an error on the console of ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null```, can you help me with this?